# Laravel blade route strange behaviour returning ? instead of / on array param

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

iam new to Laravel and stumbled upon a (at least for me) strange behaviour:
i have following link to a named route:

```
<a href="{{ route('nameofroute',$var->id) }}">{{ $var->desc }}</a>
```

generated link is

```
way/to/myroute?100
```

instead of

```
way/to/myroute/100
```

iam using this on various places in my code, and its working as intended normally, i guess it is something with my routes.php but i cant find something wrong.

```
Route::get('way/to/myroute', [ 'as' => 'nameofroute', 'uses' => 'MyController@getMyfunc' ]);
```

Comment: Post your route declaration for this route.

Comment: you are right, Terrys answer wasnt fully working as he posted before i  added the route part. Still he pointed out the missing {id} in the routes.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the parameter `{idoranything}` so your getting `way/to/myroute?100` instead of `way/to/myroute/100`. Your route declaration should be something like this:

```
Route::get('way/to/myroute/{id}', [ 'as' => 'nameofroute', 'uses' => 'MyController@getMyfunc' ]);
```

So the `url` could be `way/to/myroute/100` and you may use `route('nameofroute',$var->id)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't set the route correctly. You need to add the ID parameter like so:

```
Route::get('/nameofroute/{id}', array('uses' => 'Controller@getRoute', 'as' => 'nameofroute'));
```

Laravel will automatically detect that you expect a parameter there and add it to the URL.